# What are the correct file locations when adding a Rails backend to a JS/HTML/CSS application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I made a game in JavaScript. I have a directory called Game, and it contains:

- `index.html`
- `app.css`
- `imgs`
- `lib`
- `vendor`

Inside of `lib` I have my own javascript files. Inside of `vendor` I have a javascript file from a third party, that is used for a specific functionality in the game. I'm using webpack to bundle my modules, and so inside of lib I also keep my bundle.js file.

I now want to add a Rails backend to the game. I am very familiar with writing code using Ruby on Rails, but there are holes in my knowledge of where certain files should go in the directory structure.

If I transform my purely javascript/html/css game into a Rails application with a single page (the root page with the game on it), where do the files I listed above go?

Here is how I think it would be:

- `index.html` would become my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`
- `app.css` would become `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`
- the contents of my `imgs` folder would go in `/public` (actually it has never made sense to me why I it never works when I put my images in `app/assets/images`, but that's another story)
- the contents of my `lib` folder would go in `app/assets/javascripts` (hope I don't have the same issue as with my images)
- and the javascript file contained in my `vendor` folder would go in `/vendor`

Is this correct? Are there any other considerations to take into account?

Comment: I dont think that your `javascript` files which are there inside your `vendor` should go inside '/vendor'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app.css file should stay in the app/assets/stylesheets folder as app.css.  Leave your application.css file alone as it will require the tree which includes your app.css file.  Your images should remain in your app/assets/images folder so when you run "bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production" for deployment it will get precompiled and added to the public folder.  Your personal js files in your lib folder should be moved to the app/assets/javascripts folder and the vendor js files should be put in the vendor js folder as you said.

In general, all assets in the vendor folder should be files/scripts done by outside sources and all personal js/css files you write should be in app/assets folders.